# Bitcoin full node, showing weird transaction in some blocks

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoin

I have a program that adds up all the transaction data and outputs the total Bitcoin in the block. It runs perfect most of the time, but every once in a while I'll get a weird transaction that throws off my output.  What would cause this to happen?

Every time I run it against my node I get the same output, but other block explorers are showing it normal.  My node is running Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.18.0.0-472733a24a9364e4c6233ccd04166a26a68cc65 on Ubuntu 18.04

Output of the block, this particular block is 605540.

910 0.128272 2482.385553
911 0.005425 2482.390978
912 0.160804 2482.551782
913 0.012542 2482.564324
914 -8642921084.551126 -8642918601.986803 <-------Offending transaction
915 0.027132 -8642918601.959671
916 0.014252 -8642918601.945419
917 0.013913 -8642918601.931505
918 2.845980 -8642918599.085526
919 0.404175 -8642918598.681351

```
    from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy, JSONRPCException  
    import time

    with open(r"/home/pi/python_scripts/blockbot/keys.txt", 'r') as 
    keys_File:  
        keys = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in keys_File]

    rpc_user = keys[4]
    rpc_password = keys[5]
    block_Value = 0
    line = 0

    rpc_connection = AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:8332"% 
   (rpc_user, rpc_password))

    print('Input Block for Transaction data: ')
    block_Count = int(input())
    block_Hash = rpc_connection.getblockhash(block_Count)
    latest_Block = rpc_connection.getblock(block_Hash)
    num_Trans = latest_Block['nTx']
    transactions = latest_Block['tx']
    block_Value = 0

    trans_F = open("Transactions.txt","w+")

    for txid in transactions:
        tx_Value = 0
        raw_Tx = rpc_connection.getrawtransaction(txid)
        decoded_Tx = rpc_connection.decoderawtransaction(raw_Tx)
        for output in decoded_Tx['vout']:
            tx_Value = tx_Value + output['value']
        line = line + 1
        block_Value = block_Value + tx_Value
        print(line, tx_Value, block_Value)
        trans_F.write('%d %f %f\r\n' %(line, tx_Value, block_Value))
    trans_F.close
```

Comment: How are you producing this output?

Comment: Python program, I posted the code, but I know it works.  It seems that transaction is messed up on my node, but I don't understand why.

Comment: What is the tx id for the tx that fails to parse correctly?

Comment: Tx-90736a2028fe2d3388820e34cd583fe9152e5932cc42522297b9b0a57f8c2fd5  Txid-15ec19722831424730a0762985d63f0bd09a93d5785d32be846ee68855111b31

Comment: "vout": [
    {
      "value": -8642921084.55112703

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to parse a segwit transaction without telling bitcoind that it is a segwit transaction.

You have two options here:

Get and parse the transaction using `bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction 90736a2028fe2d3388820e34cd583fe9152e5932cc42522297b9b0a57f8c2fd5 1` - the 1 at the end tells the bitcoind to return a JSON response instead of hex.

OR

Explicitly tell decoderawtransaction to treat it as a segwit transaction using

```
bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction 02000000000101105c15e86a01f4e449410c4c75fc3640827abbb3387acd87d87a5a5af4e9846f0100000017160014afc0c9d7a93b6736719f967536700d04472a9b29feffffff0212deac000000000017a914f0ba10f2a6f82f2c3b55b37b29f8dfd45adc34f287006a18000000000017a9148e5d27e3ae870f7611809635bfc1ccfed62c0c108702473044022025221370b4a334c26a267bc5ae4301c06d9e41023faafbe4902b3f7f3a5b4a590220327bc1635eefd86a57e51884277351faf8cfed4fb6a89e754dc493649e1c676b0121029d26a8dc5e3a27c571684012fbaf8c0cedad5ef4fefd6c737c2c1988d97cdadb623d0900 true
```

The `true` at the end tells bitcoind to treat the raw tx as a segwit transaction.

Your wrapper/library around bitcoind's RPC should have some way to set these additional options.

Comment: Thanks! That was it.  Now I just have to figure out how to add it to my code.  But I at least know why it's happening now.

Comment: For anyone using the python_bitcoinrpc to decode segwit transactions, you have to put a flag at the end of the decoderawtransaction call.  Like so:

flag = True  
segwit_Tx = rpc_connection.decoderawtransaction(raw_Tx, flag)